# "Медовичёк" или" медовичок"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется - "медовичёк" или "медовичок"?

Answer (score 2):

Правильно - *медовичок*.

Вот правило http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/360151-kak-pravilno-durachok-ili-durachjok.html

В суффиксах имён существительных после шипящих под ударением пишется буква "о", а в безударном положении – "е".